# i want to "include" a page when i select "jQuery UI radio button".

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

```
 <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"><label for="radio1">Choice1</label>
 <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="radio2">Choice2</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"><label for="radio3">Choice3</label>
</div>
<?php
//     if (radio == Choice1){
//     include ("file1.php");
//     }
//     elseif (radio == Choice2){
//     include ("file2.php");
//     }
//     else {
//     include ("file3.php");
//     }
?>
```

> i want to "include" a page when i select "jQuery UI radio button". 
>   Please tell me with a little script. i am not expert on jquery or ajax

Comment: you want to include it or load it..?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to catch the `click` event on your radio-boxes.

then check if it is checked or not

if so, load your content via ajax i.e.

something like:

```
$('input[name=radio]').each(function(){ 
    $(this).bind('click', function(){ 
... checking and ajax loading ... 
    });
});
```

here some links:

- http://api.jquery.com/bind/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp